# CORS Issue with Legacy System - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header

Tags: javascript, html, cors, cross-domain, activexobject

--Ajax Method Call to get the response in terms of HTML format

```
function send_with_ajax(brand) {
    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { alertContents(httpRequest); };  
    httpRequest.open("GET", "https://XXXX--LEGACY SYSTEM--XXXX", true);
    httpRequest.setRequestHeader( 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'https://XXXX--LEGACY SYSTEM's IP Address--XXXX/');
    httpRequest.send(null);
}

function alertContents(httpRequest) {
    alert(httpRequest.readyState);
    if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
        // everything is good, the response is received
        if ((httpRequest.status == 200) || (httpRequest.status == 0)) {
            //Get the httpRequest.responseText
        } else {
            //Error with the response or Failed to load the response;
        }
    }
}
```

Hi, In the above JS code, I have created an activeX object to hit a legacy system(Which mean no CORS related APIs are present in the endpoint Java).
Following the same, I expect to receive an HTML format type response. This is working fine from IE(in HTML code type) but when tried the same using Chrome(ported to HTML5 code type), I ended up with CORS issue. Ok...It happens, And i'm trying to set the header here to get it resolved but it also went in vain. Is there a way to resolve this. Please be cautious that i'm trying to interact with a legacy system where endpoint java component cannot have any amendments. Kindly Help !!!

Comment: `access-control-allow-origin` headers are set in the **response**, not the request ... in fact, setting them in the request can have detrimental effects

Comment: `legacy system where endpoint java component cannot have any amendments` - basically you have two choices, amend the server, or use the server your page is served from to make the request for you

Comment: You were about to say that both the client and services should reside in the same machine to get this issue resolved...isn't it ???

Comment: no ... you obviously have TWO servers - one which serves your page with the code you showed above, and the second is the legacy server .. you would use the first server as a proxy for the legacy - as stated in the answer by TJ Crowder

Answer (score 0):

You don't set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the *request*, you set it (and the several other required headers) in the *response*. The server is where the decision of whether cross-origin requests are allowed is made (a decision which the browser then implements).

> i'm trying to interact with a legacy system where endpoint java component cannot have any amendments

Then you cannot directly query it with ajax from another origin. Instead you need some kind of proxy, such as a second process running on the server (or on another server) that you can query which, in turn, queries the one you actually want to talk to. That works because the SOP applies to requests from browsers, but non-browsers can do cross-origin requests if they like.

There are several "CORS proxy" projects out there (that's a reasonable search term for them), both for you to run on your servers and ones you can use directly like crossorigin.me (just an example, not an endorsement; no idea if it's any good). If you use a service, naturally you have to trust them, as all the data (in both directions) flows through their server...

Comment: Is there any other way without using an intermittent component(Proxy Server) ??? Mine is a standalone HTML page...which doesn't require any other dependencies... And eventually it works well with IE in a traditional HTML way... I want to retain this property in chrome as well for HTML5 tooo...

If nothing else are the ways...will have to go with the proxy server ideology :)

Comment: @VijayLMarcelin: Well, as I say above, there are services that will do the proxying for you. You can also [use YQL as a cross-domain proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax), but whether that works for you will depend a lot on what you're reading from the other origin.

Comment: Thanks @CrowderTJ  ! Will check it out

Answer (score 0):

A way to overcome the cross-origin restriction is using the yql yahoo console. You can transfer data (also html for your case) between sites with different domains. You can check it out [here](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/). At the left menu go to data->html and make a query like `select * from html where url="http://your.different.domain.com"` Then simply use the url the yahoo provides without restriction problems